# Case When Exists In Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, case, exists

I am trying to check whether an ID is present in a subquery. I have ran just the subquery and it produces a list of all the ID's which have a fee against it, so what I want to do is check whether the ID in the main query is present in the subquery. If it's present then return 1, else return 0.
This is an easy query but I have no idea where i'm going wrong, I tried using `exists` rather than `in` but this does not work either.

```
case when debtor._rowid in (
          select distinct note.debtorid from note 
              left join debtor on note.debtorid = debtor._rowid
              left join fee    on fee.debtorid = debtor._rowid
          where fee.type = "Enforcement" and note.type = "Stage") 
     then 1 else 0 end) as `Enforcement`
```

Below is the entire code, when I remove the above code from the main query below, it works perfectly, so there's something wrong in my case statement.

```
with cte_1
as
(
    select 
        debtor._rowid as casref
        ,concat(date_format(date_sub(debtor._createddate, interval 3 month), '%y'), '/', date_format(date_add(debtor._createddate, interval 9 month), '%y')) as `F/Y`
        ,date_format(debtor._createddate, '%M %Y') as `Loaded Month`
        ,ifnull(concat(date_format(date_sub(debtor.offence_date, interval 3 month), '%y'), '/', date_format(date_add(debtor.offence_date, interval 9 month), '%y')),'-') as `LO F/Y`
        ,coalesce(date_format(debtor.offence_date,'%M %Y'),'-') as `Liability Order Month`
        ,scheme.name as  `Scheme`
        ,branch.name as `Branch`
        ,count(debtor._rowid) as `Cases Received`
        ,count(debtor.linkid) as `LinkID`
        ,(case 
            when concat(date_format(date_sub(debtor._createddate, interval 3 month), '%y'), '/', date_format(date_add(debtor._createddate, interval 9 month), '%y'))
             = ifnull(concat(date_format(date_sub(debtor.offence_date, interval 3 month), '%y'), '/', date_format(date_add(debtor.offence_date, interval 9 month), '%y')),'-')
             then 1 else 0 end ) as `Same Year`
        , case when debtor._rowid in (
                    select distinct note.debtorid from note 
                        left join debtor on note.debtorid = debtor._rowid
                        left join fee    on fee.debtorid = debtor._rowid
                    where fee.type = "Enforcement" 
                    and note.type = "Stage") 
                then 1 else 0 end) as `Enforcement`

        from debtor
        left join clientscheme          on debtor.clientschemeID = clientscheme._rowid
        left join scheme                on clientscheme.schemeID = scheme._rowid
        left join branch                on clientscheme.branchID = branch._rowid
        left join fee                   on debtor._rowid = fee.debtorid
        left join note                  on debtor._rowid = note.debtorid
    where clientscheme.branchID in (1,10,24)
    and debtor._createddate >= '2017-04-01'
    group by debtor._rowid
)
,
cte_2
as
(
select 
    `F/Y`
    ,`Loaded Month` 
    ,`LO F/Y`
    ,`Liability Order Month`
    ,`Scheme`
    ,`Branch`
    ,sum(`Cases Received`) as `Case Count`
    ,sum(`LinkID`) as `Linked Accounts`
    ,sum(`Same Year`) as `In Year LO`
    ,sum(Enforcement) as `Enforcement Applied`
from cte_1
group by 
    `Loaded Month`
    ,`Liability Order Month`
    ,`Scheme`
    , `Branch`

)

select 
    `F/Y`
    ,`Loaded Month`
    ,`LO F/Y`
    ,`Liability Order Month`
    ,`Scheme`
    ,`Branch`
    ,`Case Count`
    ,`Linked Accounts`
    ,round((`Linked Accounts`/`Case Count`),2) * 100 as `% of Linked Accounts`
    ,round((`In Year LO`/`Case Count`),2) * 100 as `In Year LO's`
    ,`Enforcement Applied`
from cte_2
```

Comment: The error message you posted is not relevant to the code. Post the code that produces the error.

Comment: @forpas i've included the entire code now so that its clearer to understand what's going on

Comment: Remove `debtor._rowid` from `case when debtor._rowid exists`: `case when exists(...`

Comment: I tried removing debtor._rowid but that still does not work

Comment: *removing debtor._rowid* clears the syntax error.

Comment: my problem is when I remove the case statement the code runs, once I add it back in, it throws an error, so i'm trying to decipher what exactly is wrong with the case statement

Comment: You posted the case statement with exists and removed it again. Delete the parenthesis after `then 1 else 0 end`.

Comment: yes I was meant to post the one using `in` rather than `exists` reason why I changed it. DUHHH I didnt realise I had an extra parenthesis, thanks for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to logically check if, for a given record in the result set, a `_noteid` value from the `debtor` table matches to a `debtors` from the `note` table.  You could rephrase your query as follows:

```
SELECT
    (d._rowid = n.debtorid) AS `Enforcement Allocated`
FROM note n
LEFT JOIN debtor d
    ON n.debtorid = d._rowid
LEFT JOIN fee f
    ON f.debtorid = d._rowid
WHERE
    f.type = 'Enforcement' AND n.type = 'Stage';
```

Note that since the output of your `CASE` expression is just 1 or 0, you may take advantage of that MySQL allows boolean expressions as values.